# How Can I Increase Performance of This MERGE Statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

I have a INSERT INTO/MERGE statement that is part of a stored procedure that needs to be really efficient. The execution plan shows that 90% of the procedure is due to the following statement shown below. The tricky part is I need to insert rows when they're not matched in the target table but also need to insert records when there are updated and have shares left over.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.#SubscriptionPeriodTemp (UserId, Shares, ProcessedShares, StartDate, EndDate)
SELECT UserId, Shares, ProcessedShares, StartDate, EndDate
FROM (
    MERGE INTO dbo.SubscriptionPeriod AS sp
    USING #ResponderOrderItem AS ob
    ON (ob.UserId = sp.UserId 
        AND ob.ContentId = sp.ContentId 
        AND sp.Status = @SubscriptionPeriodStatusOpen 
        AND sp.EndDate > @StartDate 
        AND sp.StartDate < @EndDate)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE 
        SET sp.Status = CASE WHEN @IsRespondingOrderOfBuyType = 1 THEN @SubscriptionPeriodStatusPurchased ELSE @SubscriptionPeriodStatusSold END,
            sp.ProcessedDate = SYSUTCDATETIME()
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT (UserId, ContentId, Status, Shares, StartDate, EndDate, CreateDate)
            VALUES (UserId, @ContentId, @SubscriptionPeriodStatusOpen, ob.ProcessedShares, @StartDate, @EndDate, SYSUTCDATETIME())
    OUTPUT $action, inserted.UserId, inserted.Shares, ob.ProcessedShares, inserted.StartDate, inserted.EndDate
) AS Changes (Action, UserId, Shares, ProcessedShares, StartDate, EndDate)
WHERE Action = 'UPDATE'
    AND Shares - ProcessedShares > 0
```

Is there a more efficient option?

**EDIT**
I should have been a bit more specific. I'd like to increase the performance of a specific stored procedure in my database and the execution plan when I run the proc shows 90% of the work is being done with this section of the code. with ~30,000 records in the `dbo.SubscriptionPeriod` table it takes ~20 seconds. This procedure is meant to be a high throughput proc being called 1000s of times per second. I think I have a long way to go :)

[Click here](http://pastebin.com/iNWz38YX) for the execution plan.

[Click here](http://1drv.ms/1IfjAS6) for the database script (70MB file). Please see line 102,786 in the stored procedure named `spAddOrderItem` for the area of concern

[Click here](http://1drv.ms/1IfjutM) for the script to run the procedure with the exact data I'm using for testing.

Comment: Why are you fixed on avoiding MERGE? It might well be the fastest option (or not, but impossible to say).

Comment: The plan looks fine and totally reasonable. If this takes 20s as you say there is either blocking or random IO going on. If this was without blocking and in-memory I'd estimate one second per execution. I think expecting 30m rows written per second is a bit much to expect!

Comment: Run the proc single-threadedly in a loop. Then, in a separate session repeatedly run sp_whoisactive and look at the wait types. What waits come up most often? Is it IO or locks? This is a simple way to profile the query.

Comment: I will try your running the proc single-threadedly in a loop. However it wasn't 20s for 30m rows but only 30k rows.

Comment: Here's what I got: CXPACKET, IO_COMPLETION and PAGEIOLATCH_SH